# Changinx Bar Charts X position on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

We have a request from customer and we need to trick the highcharts bar view.

The problem is our series contain timestamp vs value but business wise this value is corresponding to previous timestamp to that value's timestamp. So we would like to show the bars in between of these timestamps.

So is there an easy way to do this in highcharts w/o playing with the points in the series.

See images below;

**Current Highchart Behaviour**
[image: Existing Chart]
**Requested Chart Behaviour**
[image: Requested Chart]

Comment: what is your code set up? is that a `datetime` x axis, or are you using `categories`? The Axis behavior depends on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xAxis.tickPositioner` in order to move ticks and `xAxis.labels.formatter` to change labels values.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/h9zjmqap/

Output:
[image]